# Каким образом применить LIKE в запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Мне нужен такой запрос, но только чтобы выбирал по даже по одному слову из предложения, а этот запрос выбирает только по точным вхождениям.

```
$item = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `id_item` FROM `x-ka` WHERE (id_pole, value) in (('2', 'слово'), ('5', 'еще')) GROUP BY `id_item` HAVING COUNT(`id_item`) = $hc");
```

Comment: разверните in в логические операторы `(id_pole=2 AND value like '...') OR (=3 AND like '...')`

Comment: @Mike то есть получается просто `WHERE (id_pole, value) in (('2', like  'слово'), ('5', like 'еще'))` ?

Comment: @Mike можно вас попросить написать в ответ мой запрос с вашим предложением?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `id_item`
  FROM `x-ka`
 WHERE (id_pole=2 AND value like '%слово%')
    OR (id_pole=5 AND value like '%еще%')
 GROUP BY `id_item`
HAVING COUNT(`id_item`) = $hc
```

Comment: как не странно, но все равно like не срабатывает. запрос получился `(id_pole=1 AND value like 'масло')` а в бд есть запись `Масло Bengo` - не выводит эту запись

Comment: и id_pole=1 в бд, как и в запросе

Comment: @Денис поправил, like же еще нужно говорить где могут встречаться любые символы, с помощью %

Comment: ага, теперь что надо. но знаете, ищет теперь даже по одной букве в слове, нельзя ли сделать чтоб только искало до или после пробела, то есть чтобы находило только целые слова.

Comment: @Денис тогда вам лучше использовать вместо like, regexp, но не знаю достаточно ли MySQL будет регулярки '\bслово\b' и вообще понимает ли он \b как границу слова